# Why are the continued fractions of non-square-root numbers ($\sqrt[a]{x}$ where $a>2$) not periodic?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

Ok, so it is quite amazing how the continued fractions for $\sqrt[2]{x}$ are always periodic for all whole numbers of $x$ (and where $x$ is not a perfect square): Here is a link I suggest at looking at: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html ...

---

The following is in the simple continued fraction form:
$$\sqrt x = a_1+ \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{a_4 + \cfrac{1}{a_5 + \cfrac{1}{a_6 + \cfrac{1}{a_7 + \cdots}}}}}}$$

For example:

The continued fraction of $\sqrt 7$ is as follows: 
$[2;1,1,1,4,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,4,\ldots]$ the period in this case is $4$... and the continued fraction can be written as:

$$[2;\overline{1,1,1,4}]$$

---

Some other examples:

$\sqrt2 = [1;\overline{2}]$ Period is 1

$\sqrt3 = [1;\overline{1,2}]$ Period is 2

$\sqrt{13} = [3;\overline{1,1,1,1,6}]$ Period is 5

$\sqrt{97} = [9;\overline{1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,18}]$ Period is 11

---

There are many other sources which show this... but why does this not work for others, such as cubic roots? I have written a java program to compute the continued fraction for the nth root of the numbers between $1$ and $100$ (excluding perfect squares,etc...) for the first 100 terms. 
Here are the results:

$\sqrt[2]{x}$: http://pastebin.com/ZcasfRyP

$\sqrt[3]{x}$: http://pastebin.com/XG9UF8hR

$\sqrt[4]{x}$: http://pastebin.com/Edp307SE

$\sqrt[5]{x}$: http://pastebin.com/9SwwPqUa

---

As you can see no period...

**So why is it periodic for square roots, but not for others?** An extension of the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a

Kind Regards

Joshua Lochner

Comment: You've done a lot of work for this, and it's a good quality post and question in general. I hope you get the answer you're looking for!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: the OP did a lot of work on writing up the question, but didn't look at the Wikipedia article on [periodic continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction). which would have saved him or her the trouble.

Comment: Periodicity means that you can write for example, with $x=\sqrt{3}: $x=1+1/(1+1/2+x))$. But this yields a **quadratic equation** (it is important to remember this fact), which have (in general) a squlre root in the expression of its zeros, ans not a cubic root, etc...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you :)

Comment: @RobArthan I have checked that out, but I would like to know 1. Why does this happen... and 2. Is there another way to write continued fractions of these irrational numbers?

Comment: @RobArthan For example: $$\pi = 3 + \frac{1^2}{6+ \frac{3^2}{6+ \frac{5^2}{6+...}}}$$ So beautiful... but can't other irrational numbers in the form: $\sqrt[a]{b}$ be written like this too?

Comment: The Wikipedia page is telling you that Euler **proved** that periodic continued fractions are roots of quadratic equations. If you are aware of that and want more information about the proof, then you have no need to inflict us with so much information in your question and your ongoing comments. Yes, the formulas are beautiful, but they are well known.

Comment: @RobArthan Ok, thank you for your comment :) ... However, is there no way... In **any** form... for other  $\sqrt[a]{b}$ to be written? Like that continued fraction for $\pi$ above... not only in simplest form...

Comment: So you want to broaden your question to include generalised continued fractions (ones where the numerators are not required to be $1$)? I hope the people who have taken the trouble to explain in their answers how Euler's proof works in the case of regular continued fractions will be delighted when you make that change to your question (which complicates the notation in the proof buts doesn't affect the outcome).

Comment: @RobArthan Well, the initial question was as stated above... I can simply ask a new question...

Comment: If you see how to deal with the generalised continued fractions, an alternative would be to add an answer of your own acknowledging the other answers and covering the case of generalised continued fractions.

Comment: @RobArthan I shall consider that, thanks!

Comment: I hope my answer below is as simple and elementary as any can be made.

Comment: @RobArthan Another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because periodicity of a simple continued fraction amounts to a quadratic equation.  I will illustrate this by means of an example:
$$
7 + \cfrac 1 {2 + \cfrac 1 {3+\cfrac 1 {9 + \cdots\vphantom{\dfrac 1 1}}}}
$$
and assume $2,\,3,\,9$ repeats.  We have
$$
7,\  \overbrace{2,3,9,}\  \overbrace{2,3,9,}\  \overbrace{2,3,9,}\  \overbrace{2,3,9,}\  \ldots
$$
This is
$$
-2 + \left(9 + \cfrac 1 {2 + \cfrac 1 {3+\cfrac 1 {9 + \cdots\vphantom{\dfrac 1 1}}}} \right) \tag 1
$$
so that $9,\ 2,\ 3$ repeats right from the beginning.

Let $x = {}$the continued fraction in $(1)$, with $9,\ 2,\ 3$ repeating.

Then we get
$$
x = 9 + \cfrac 1 {2 + \cfrac 1 {3 + \cfrac 1 x}}
$$
Then, since $\dfrac 1 {3+\cfrac 1 x} = \dfrac x {3x+1}$, we have
$$
x = 9 + \cfrac 1 {2 + \cfrac x {3x+1}}.
$$
Now multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction after $9+\cdots$ by $3x+1$, getting
$$
x = 9 + \dfrac{3x+1}{7x+2}
$$
so
$$
x = \frac{66x+ 19}{7x+2}.
$$
Multiply both sides by $7x+2$:
$$
x(7x+2) = 66x+19.
$$
And there you have a quadratic equation.

Comment: An extension of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to show this is the contrapositive: if a continued fraction is periodic then its value is a quadratic.

To see this, note that if we have $y = [a_1; a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n, x]$ for reals $x,y$ and integers $a_i$, then we can write $y=\dfrac{mx+n}{px+q}$ for some integers $m, n, p, q$.  (This is easy to prove by induction - note that if $z=[a_2; a_3, \ldots, a_n, x]$ $= \dfrac {m'x+n'}{p'x+q'}$, then $y=a_1+\dfrac1z$ $=a_1+\dfrac{p'x+q'}{m'x+n'}$ $=\dfrac{a_1m'x+a_1n'+p'x+q'}{m'x+n'}$ $=\dfrac{(a_1m'+p')x+(a_1n'+q')}{m'x+n'}$ is clearly of the required form.)

Now, if the continued fraction for $x$ is periodic then we have $x=[a_1; a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n, x]$, so by the above there are integers with $x=\dfrac{mx+n}{px+q}$.  But now multiply both sides by $px+q$ to get $px^2+qx=mx+n$, or $px^2+(q-m)x-n=0$, so that $x$ is a solution to this quadratic equation.

To answer the question about patterns in the continued fractions of other numbers: to the best of my knowledge, nothing is known about the continued fractions of e.g. cube roots — not even whether their coefficients are bounded! — though it's known that they can't grow too quickly: this is a corollary of [Roth's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem), which bounds the so-called *irrationality measure* of algebraic numbers (how well they can be approximated by rationals).  On the other hand, there is a special class of (transcendental) numbers for which more information on the continued fraction representation is known: certain [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) have continued fractions with complicated recursive (almost fractal) structures; see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html and some of the references there for a little more information on this.

Comment: An extension of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a

Answer (score 2):

it does not work because, given a strictly periodic continued fraction, we can construct the 2 by 2 matrix that comes from it. Then we get the integer quadratic form that goes with that automorphism matrix. Finally, we get the "quadratic irrational" larger than one that goes with that.

Alright, we are dealing with an indefinite binary quadratic form, $$ f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2, $$ with positive non-square discriminant $$ \Delta = B^2 - 4AC. $$
We find the minimum solution $(\tau, \sigma)$ to the Pell type equation
$$  \tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4.  $$
Then the matrix that generates the ($+1$) automorphism group of the form is
$$ P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{\tau - B \sigma}{2} &  -C \sigma \\
A \sigma & \frac{\tau + B \sigma}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The Hessian matrix of the form is
$$ H =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 A &  B \\
B  & 2C
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and the automorphism matrices satisfy
$$ P^T H P = H. $$
In the discussion below, the "quadratic irrational" that has that continued fraction comes from the quadratic formula going right to left, that is
$$ \frac{-13 - \sqrt {345}}{-22} \approx 1.4351898  $$

Next, a CF that is "eventually periodic" is just a rearrangement of the quadratic irrational.  Let me give a "reduced" quadratic form as example, give me a minute

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 4 13 -11

  0  form              4          13         -11


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   4 13 -11   delta  -1
1  form   -11 9 6   delta  2
2  form   6 15 -5   delta  -3
3  form   -5 15 6   delta  2     ambiguous  
4  form   6 9 -11   delta  -1
5  form   -11 13 4   delta  3
6  form   4 11 -14   delta  -1
7  form   -14 17 1   delta  17
8  form   1 17 -14   delta  -1     ambiguous  
9  form   -14 11 4   delta  3
10  form   4 13 -11


  form   4 x^2  + 13 x y  -11 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 108   y = 155 disc 345 dSqrt 18  M_Ratio  20.25
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-2029  -8008
-2912  -11493
=========================================
```

Given the matrix I call "Automorph," here is how we recover the form:

```
? m = [ 2029, 8008; 2912, 11493]
%2 = 
[2029 8008]

[2912 11493]

? matdet(m)
%3 = 1
? 2029 + 11493
%4 = 13522
? gcd(5,3)
%5 = 1
? gcd(2912, 8008)
%6 = 728
-
? tr = 2029 + 11493
%7 = 13522
? g = gcd(2912, 8008)
%8 = 728
? tr^2 - 4
%9 = 182844480

? rat = ( tr^2 - 4) / g^2
%12 = 345

? tr^2 - 345 * g^2
%14 = 4
? 
? a = 2912 / g
%16 = 4

? b = ( tr - 2 * 2029) / g
%18 = 13

? c = -8008 / g
%17 = -11
```

Given the purely periodic continued fraction with repeated part 
$$ 1,2,3,2,1,3,1,17,1,3,   $$  the resulting matrix is the product of little 2 by 2 matrices:

```
? a1 = [0,1; 1,1]
%1 = 
[0 1]

[1 1]

? a2 = [0,1; 1,2]
%2 = 
[0 1]

[1 2]

? a3 = [0,1; 1,3]
%3 = 
[0 1]

[1 3]

? a17 = [0,1; 1,17]
%4 = 
[0 1]

[1 17]

? auto = a1 * a2 * a3 * a2 * a1 * a3 * a1 * a17 * a1 *a3
%5 = 
[2029 8008]

[2912 11493]

?
```

Comment: I am sorry but it is very hard to follow you... I have a faint idea of what the matrix you are speaking about is but you should add a reference. About the program you give : I understand nothing. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @JeanMarie my favorite is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Given the Hessian matrix $H$ of second partial derivatives, a matrix in the automorphism group of the form is some $P$ such that $P^T H P = H. $ Tell you what, could you give me, say, four positive integers, I will show you the resulting matrix and quadratic form that go with that strictly periodic continued fraction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and  the reference. I understand a little now why you do that. But the output of your program is a little cryptic for the beotian (I think to me and to the OP, even more). A little reference, even not simple, as (http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/editions/biblio/files/lachaud/1988e.pdf) could be of some help for understanding what a quadratic form is and what it is here for. :)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, that's nice. On page 33 he discusses the automorphism matrices. He does not seem to turn it around to say that a string of an even number of cf "digits" defines an automorphism matrix as a product of little 2 by 2 matrices, and this matrix can be used to reconstruct an underlying quadratic form. Finally, this gives a "quadratic irrational." I typed in more stuff in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks : the explanations you give in your new version are very helpful.

Comment: @WillJagy An extension of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a

Comment: @JoshuaLochner I noticed. If you require the partial denominators and the partial numerators to be periodic, you again get quadratics, simply because you get the fixed points of a Mobius transformation with integer coefficients. If, as you did there, you allow one of these sets to grow without bound, therefore not repeat, you cannot say what you get. Note that the (simple) continued fraction for $e$ is like that, with the pure pattern for some Mobius related quantity, evidently $e-1.$

Comment: @JoshuaLochner I recommend this inexpensive recent book, http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions

Answer (score 2):

The idea is quite simple. Suppose that $$x=[a_0;\overline{a_1 , \dots , a_k}]$$ is a real number whose continued fraction is periodic. Then it satisfies the equation
$$x- a_0= \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{\frac{\dots}{a_{k-1}\frac{1}{a_k+(x-a_0)}}}}$$
which can be transformed by a quadratic equation. with integer coefficients. For example, the number $x=[2; \overline{1,4}]$ satisfies
$$x-2= \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{x-2}}}$$ which is equivalent to the quadratic equation
$$(x-2)(5x-9)=4x-7$$

So, all periodic numbers must be quadratic.

Comment: Interesting comment! Thanks :) ...

Comment: You don't need to write $$ a + \frac 1 {b+\frac 1 {c + \frac 1 {d + \frac 1 e}}}. $$ You can write $$ a + \cfrac 1 {b+\cfrac 1 {c + \cfrac 1 {d + \cfrac 1 e}}}.  $$ This is done by using \cfrac{}{}. $\qquad$

Comment: An extension of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898902/periodic-continued-fractions-of-non-square-root-numbers-sqrtax-where-a